# Remove Sublime Text red pop-ups

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

How do I remove the irritating red pop-up errors that now appear on Sublime Text?

For example in this image:

[image: Annoying red pop-up]

I have seen people refer to these as issues with Typescript but I am on Ubuntu and don't seem to have this package installed.

I have tried all the Anaconda settings, but this seems to be a Sublime Text thing.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing there are `Inline Build Errors`; Sublime catches the output of a build when you execute one, and if that information contains location information in the file along with an error and the appropriate setting is enabled, it will add inline errors (called Phantoms) into the document at the error locations to give your errors more context.

This happens without regard to the language or platform that you're using, which is why you may have only turned up examples for TypeScript.

In core Sublime Text, this is controlled by the following setting, which as seen here is enabled by default:

```json
// Shows build errors just under the line on which they occur.
"show_errors_inline": true,
```

Setting that setting to `false` in your user preferences should resolve the problem for you. If it doesn't, then a third party package is also injecting build errors (or similar) into your document as well and isn't honouring the setting above.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I added "show_errors_inline": false, to the user settings. I didn't realise this was Sublime Text behaviour, I assumed it was an Anaconda setting.